# Cauchy's Theorem Application Example

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

My professor went over an example in class and I am kind of confused. We are giving a proof of the theorem that $\forall a \gt 0, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+ib)t} \, dt \, \colon= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{0}^{R} e^{-(a+ib)t} \, dt = \frac{1}{a+ib}$.

So, to prove, we integrated over the triangle with sides $\gamma_1 = Ra$, $\gamma_2 = R(a+ib)$, and hypotenuse $\gamma_3$. Then, we parameterized them:
$$\gamma_1 = t, t \in [0, Ra]$$
$$\gamma_2 = aR + ibt, t \in [0, 1]$$
$$\gamma_3 = t(a+ib), t \in [0, \mathbb{R}]$$

Note: hypotenuse travels outwards from origin is intended.

Then, by Cauchy's Theorem, $$\int_{\gamma_1}e^{-z}\,dz + \int_{\gamma_2}e^{-z}\,dz - \int_{\gamma_3}e^{-z}\,dz = 0$$

So, $$\int_{\gamma_3}e^{-z} \, dz = (a+ib) \int_{0}^{R}e^{-t(a+ib)} \, dt$$

This follows from $\int f(z) \, dz = \int \gamma (t) \cdot \gamma ' (t) \, dt$.

$$\Rightarrow \int_{\gamma_1}e^{-z} \, dz = \int_{0}^{Ra} e^{-t} \, dt \rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t} \, dt = 1$$

So, $$\text{if} \space z = Ra + ibt, t \in [0, R] \Rightarrow \vert e^{-z} \vert = e^{-Ra}$$

This is the step I'm confused about. What is the motivation behind this substitution? Where does it come from? How does that imply RHS? I think I am missing something relatively simple, but I just cannot see it.

I will now finish the proof, just for sake of completeness:

$$\Bigg| \int_{\gamma_2} e^{-z} \, dz \Bigg| \le e^{-Ra} L(\gamma_2) = e^{-Ra} \vert b \vert R = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow (a+bi) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+ib)t} \, dt = 1 + \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg| \int_{\gamma_2} e^{-z} \, dz \Bigg| = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow (a+bi) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+ib)t} = \frac{1}{a+ib}$$

口

Comment: That substitution is just parametrizing the curve $\gamma_2$, and using the fact that $|e^{z}|=e^{\Re(z)}$

Comment: $e^{\mathfrak{R}(z)} = e^{\text{Re}(z)}$? Sorry, I'm not familiar with this notation, but I think this is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's how \Re renders in latex.

Comment: Ah then yes, I suppose I just forgot that $\vert e^z \vert = e^{\Re(z)}$. I guess the rest of it is quite straightforward. Having some difficulties reproducing ML-estimation from scratch without looking back on previous work at the moment, but hoping it will come eventually.